# Cocoa script Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, sketchapp, cocoascript

I need to run a long running loop in a background thread, and update the UI once a while on the main thread. How would I be able to do this with Cocoa script ?

I am trying to create a Sketch plugin.

Thank you.